# Javascript for sticky/fixed/sliding scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, css-position

I'm trying to achieve that effect where sections slide over each other as you scroll (kind of what you get with a fixed background position).

I was able to use this jQuery library (Sticky-Kit) http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/ as a starting point.

I have a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ntz2V/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="A">...
    </section>
    <section id="B">...
    </section>
    <section id="C">...
    </section>
    <section id="D">...
    </section>
</div>
```

Javascript used with z-index fix so the section below will slide **over** the previous one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#A").stick_in_parent().css('z-index', -1);
    $("#B").stick_in_parent().css('z-index', -1);
    $("#C").stick_in_parent().css('z-index', -1);
    $("#D").stick_in_parent().css('z-index', -1);
});
```

**However it has some issues and I'm wondering if there is another way to do this.**

For one thing, the Stick-Kit uses a hidden div overlay such that the previous links become un-clickable as you scroll. I've found no z-index trick to avoid this, as the "stuck" sections have `position: fixed` but the hidden div cannot be `fixed` position. It also breaks link anchors if you have scrolled to the bottom of the page (i.e. anything that is "stuck" cannot be reached with an anchor).

Improvements or alternative suggestions welcome.